# Taking table data located in mysql from php script into swift text view as i click a button

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get my php script data read and parsed into the ios app and then outputted in a text view when i click the pull data button on the storyboard

```
import UIKit
class ViewControllerPull: UIViewController {

    let URL_PULL_TEAM = "http://cgi.soic.indiana.edu/~wesmtayl/capstoneselect.php"

    @IBAction func pullData(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let requestURL = NSURL(string: URL_PULL_TEAM)
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL! as URL)

        //setting the method to post
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        //creating the post parameter by concatenating the keys and values from text field
        let postParameters = "username=\(username.text!)";

        //adding the parameters to request body
        request.httpBody = postParameters.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        //creating a task to send the post request
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil{
                print("error is \(error)")
                return;
            }

            //print("response = \(response!)")

            //let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            //print("responseString = \(responseString!)")
            let values = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSArray
            let user = values[0] as! NSDictionary
            //You have to read the json in as a Dictionary after you have indexed it out of the array you read it in from
```

Comment: if you just read then you don`t do a post (see how REST works and wich request method you should use) btw a post to your url don`t change the data

Comment: dont snip your code in the middle of the method. make it a full example

Comment: pls remove the php tag - it is not php related

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=JSONSerialization+swift3

Comment: or use https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire